# Curl and Vector Fields

Tags: calculus, vector-fields

I am having real difficulty knowing how to approach this question, so any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Consider the vector field:

$$ \vec{G} = -3xz^2\vec{i} + z^3\vec{k} $$

FInd a vector field $\vec{F}$, such that:

$$ \vec{G} = \nabla \times \vec{F} $$

Hint: Look for a vector field in the form $ \vec{F} = F\vec{j}$

I am assuming I am looking for a way to exploit the fact that the $\vec{j}$ term in the original vector field is zero?

Many thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: Approaching what question?

Comment: Sorry - I was editing the equations. The post should make sense now.

Comment: Have you even tried using the hint?

Comment: Is $G$ stated correctly? It's not divergence-free and so cannot be written as the curl of another vector field.

Comment: Sorry - I realised I missed out a z term (I was trying to get to grips with the notation). I have corrected it now.

Comment: I have tried using the hint, I'm just confused as to how it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition of the curl is
$$
-3xz^2\mathbf{i} + z^3\mathbf{k} =
\begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k}\\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\\
F_x & F_y & F_z
\end{vmatrix}
$$
Then you evaluate the determinant.

Comment: Thank you - this gives me a starting point. I think I can see how to proceed.

Comment: Not a problem.  You can now equate the i, j, and k pieces and work from there.